# In Unbroken, how were the actors made to look malnourished?

Tags: effects, unbroken

After the two plane crash survivors are rescued from the ocean, they are brought to a small concentration camp in the jungle.  At one point, both men are brought out into the light and appear severely malnourished, with visible ribs and sunken abdomens.  Were anorexic people cast as body "doubles"? Was this CGI (like Gollum)? Or was this accomplished another way?

Comment: They weren't _made_ to look malnourished, they _were_ malnourished.

Comment: In almost the whole movie, yes, they were malnourished. However I'm asking about that specific scene in the jungle concentration camp. They are much skinnier in that scene than anywhere else in the movie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.etonline.com/news/154892_unbroken_cast_reveals_what_it_like_to_have_angelina_jolie_as_a_boss/),

> In order to get the authentic look of POWs, Angelina put stars Jack
> O'Connell, Garrett Hedlund and Finn Wittrock on strict 700-calorie
> diets. While the dietary challenge presented obstacles, Angelina
> expressed her gratitude in a way that made it all worth it.
>
> "The funny thing is we'd all be on set and everybody's kind of
> complaining and starving," Garrett said. "[We were] on these emaciated
> diets, and Angelina would show up on set and be like, 'You guys look
> great!'"

And [this article, in the words of one of the actors, John Magaro](http://www.ohio.com/entertainment/rich-heldenfels/stow-grad-john-magaro-takes-on-physical-challenges-to-be-in-unbroken-1.552745),

> His prison-camp experiences alone, like those of Zamperini and other
> inmates, were harrowing, laden with starvation and abuse. Just to
> convey that, Magaro said the actors spent days covered in grime,
> including head-to-toe makeup resembling coal dust, and were thinned
> down considerably.
>
> “There was a strict, strict diet that we were on, all the POWs as well
> as the raft guys. We had a nutritionist who kind of gave us a protocol
> and we followed it,” Magaro said of his three-month shoot in Australia
> in late 2013.
>
> “It was a lot of cutting calories with a lot of cardio and exercise. I
> lost close to 35 pounds. I’m usually around 140 and I got down to 105.
> … It was difficult, but you have to remind yourself what story you’re
> trying to tell, and you want to do justice to the story. Everyone was
> very committed to it.”

So the actor did physically lose the weight with an extreme diet.
There's no shortage of articles talking about how Angelina Jolie took on the same (or similar) diet out of sympathy for the actors and that's why she's so skinny lately.

There have been many movies where the actors have gone on crash/extreme diet to achieve the emaciated look. Like for instance Matthew McConaughey's **Dallas Buyer's Club** look.

Comment: So the guy was already a slim 140 and rode a 700-calorie diet down to 105? How does the employer get away with such abuse of employees? According to WebMD, "Severely slashing calories may lead to weight loss, but the lost weight includes precious muscle and lowers metabolism. Drastic calorie restriction also causes a shift toward a higher percentage of body fat, which increases the risk for metabolic syndrome and type 2 diabetes."

Comment: Well, it's not like they just randomly put the actors on starvation rations....they would have doctors and nutritionists on staff/call, and they would have a plan and diet all thought out (the article does mentions a nutritionist). I'm sure the actors went in knowing they were going to have to go through that weight loss process. And like I said, extreme weight loss/gain for a role is not a new phenomenon. You know Christian Bale and his Batman bod? Back in 2004, he went from that to a walking skeleton (lost 63 lbs!) for The Machinist. The pictures are scary.

Comment: Thanks for the research and the answer, Trish! I'm curious in particular about one or two shots in the jungle (after the ordeal on the raft), but it could be that the camera angle really emphasized their emaciation.

Answer (score 1):

[This link seems to say that it's CGI](http://www.techinsider.io/digital-retouching-actors-in-movies-2016-4?utm_content=buffere849a&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer-ti)

> Today, Christian Bale wouldn't need to drop a deadly 63 pounds for *The Machinist.* Digital retouching can take the physical element out of preparing for a role. For example, Jack O'Connell was saved from having to lose all the weight necessary to play a Nazi concentration camp prisoner in the Angelina Jolie-directed film *Unbroken*.